# how to compare the fied password in master.dbo.syslogins in ms sql 2008

Tags: sql-server

i have a form login and want to check if a login name and password match with name and password in system table master.dbo.syslogins but a column password was encrypted. a procedure like this :

```
    create proc checklogin(@name nchar(10), @password nvarchar, @tb nchar(10) out)
as
if Exists (select * from master.dbo.syslogins where name = @name and password=@password)
begin
set @tb='success';
else set @tb='fail';
```

i cant compare password because it was encrypted in database.I want to know if there is another way to check or how to decrypt password.any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PWDCOMPARE() function.

```
select * from master.dbo.syslogins 
where name = @name and PWDCOMPARE(@password,password) = 1
```

Comment: Changed answer to use the PWDCOMPARE() function instead of PWDENCRYPT().